# ALTER TABLE to ADD COLUMN with Python variable in MySQL table after API response

Tags: mysql

I need to ALTER TABLE posts, ADD column product_id, and insert the product_id Python variable into my MySQL table *after* the API response. The output of the variable (which is returned/parsed from the response successfully) looks similar to this:
`prod_ABc123`

I'm new here and have tried everything I could find on the Internet (including ALTER TABLE, UPDATE, and any posts I could find, etc.). Baffled why it’s not working. Can anyone help please? Everything except the ALTER TABLE works:

```
try:
    """
    Add user input to database
    """
    conn = get_db_connection()
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO posts (title, content, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
                 (title, content, price))
    conn.commit()

    """
    Create product and pass product id and metadata price in create product response to create product price
    """
    product = Product.create(name=title, description=content, metadata={'amount': price})
    get_product_response = json.dumps(product)
    load_product_response = json.loads(get_product_response)
    product_id = load_product_response['id']
    price = load_product_response['metadata']['amount']
    Price.create(product=product_id, unit_amount=price, currency='usd')
    print(f'The {product_id} product was added with a price of ${price}.')

    """
    Add product id to database 
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    prod_query = "ALTER TABLE posts ADD (product_id) TEXT NOT NULL, INSERT INTO posts VALUES (?)"
    cur.execute(prod_query, product_id)
    cur.commit()
```

The answers provided by the posters here were very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you're using MySql server, the parameter marker is %s for mysql-connector while for Microsoft SQL, the parameter marker is ? with pyodbc connector. So please take note.

For the insert statement, here it is, based on all you have told me so far:

```
  conn = (establish your database connection here)
 cursor = conn.cursor()
 sql = cursor.execute("INSERT INTO posts(title, content, price, product_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
 (yourtitleTextField.text(),
  yourContentTextField.text(), 
  yourPriceTextField.text(), 
  yourProductIDtextfield.text() )
  )

conn.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case, I'm using SQLite (https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/). ? seems to work okay.

Comment: Updated my post, still getting null value. And I know the product_id variable (populating this field) is okay, because of the print statement returned just before this when I created the product: `The prod_Abc123dh2 product was added with a price of $15.` Thoughts?

Comment: In your apps, what are your content fields, price fields, title fields and your productId fields? What did you name their lineEdits (textfields)?

Comment: The product_id variable parses the value of an API response (see post w/comment "Create product and pass product id.."). The other fields are for user input in a form: title = request.form['title']
content = request.form['content']
price = request.form['price']

Comment: I have given you the solution to your problem. From your codes, identify the textfields (lineEdits) and substitute them in my answer.  Good night

Answer (score 2):

In relational world, ALTER TABLE is DDL command & INSERT is a DML command. You need to separate your commands by understanding the syntax.

General syntax:

--ALTER to Add column (changing table definition)

```
ALTER TABLE <tble_name> ADD COLUMN (<col_name> <data_type>);
```

--INSERT data/row

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> [(col1, col2, ...)] VALUES (val1, val2, ...);
```

A general advice, since DDL commands are usually one-time execution commands, better separate them out.

Comment: Thanks. When I separated these out and execute the variables, I was able to add the column successfully:
add_column = 'ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN product_id varchar(32)'
conn.execute(add_column)
But it didn't add the "product_id" variable into the new column, any advice? prod_query = 'INSERT INTO posts (product_id) VALUES (?)' conn.execute(prod_query, product_id)

Comment: It depends on your database if it returns an error if your SQL statement errors out.  Usually, you would get an error if posts table has any other column constraints like NOT NULL, primary key etc.. To troubleshoot clearly, execute that INSERT SQL directly on your database & see what error you are getting.

Comment: When I ran this in the db: ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN product_id varchar(32)
INSERT INTO posts (product_id) VALUES (?) > I got an error with the INSERT command: Execution finished with errors.
Result: near "INSERT": syntax error
At line 1:
ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN product_id varchar(32)
INSERT

Comment: Yes, put your DDL & DML in separate statements. And if you still want to execute multiple SQL statements in one statement, separate them by ";".

Comment: To clarify, the ALTER TABLE command in a separate statement works great as you suggested. But the INSERT INTO separate command to add "product_id" value to the column does not work, is this right to insert the value in the column? `INSERT INTO posts (product_id) VALUES (?), product_id` My other column names are title, content, price.

Comment: Your INSERT gives error if 'posts' table has any other column level constraints like NOT NULL, primary key etc. are restricting, assuming your ALTER command is not in same SQL statement. If both are in same statement, ALTER command fails & next INSERT command doesn't execute. So execute them separately directly on database to see what is the actual error.

Comment: If you're sure the product_id column has been added to your table, then you can use: INSERT INTO tablename(Product_id) VALUES(1002), (1209), where 1002 and 1209 are examples of your product_id. To check if the product_id column exists in your database table, use this command "SELECT * FROM yourTableName"

Comment: @CEO When I ran this >> ALTER TABLE posts ADD COLUMN product_id varchar(32)
INSERT INTO tablename(Product_id) VALUES(1002), (1209) >> I get "Result: near "INSERT": syntax error"

Comment: @KiranM Thanks. Sorry just saw your comment. That's true, the other columns use TEXT NOT NULL. However, ALTER was successful. INSERT doesn't execute. They are separate. I've updated the post.

Comment: No, do it one at a time. First check the columns in your table using SELECT * FROM yourTableName.  If product_id column isn't there, then run this command: ALTER TABLE posts ADD product_id varchar(20) not null. Run it first before you try to run the INSERT statement

Comment: Are you trying to insert from an application you developed or you're trying to insert from the SQLite server?

Comment: @CEO Adding the input in localhost via Python-Flask app. Also tried the commands in DB Browser for SQLite. The ALTER TABLE variable/command was already successful, it's a separate command, and I can see the product_id column in the db. Just the INSERT INTO that's causing problems now.

Comment: @Tucker, I edited my answer. Kindly have a look

Comment: @CEO Trying now.

Comment: @CEO Will do. Updated my post. Still getting a NULL value. Appreciate your help though.